# how to go back to the previous slide on clicking left arrow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<nav id="next-btn">
        <a href="#" >
            <img src="img/right.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </nav>
    <nav id="prev-btn">
        <a href="#" >
            <img src="img/left.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </nav>



 $('#next-btn').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!isTransitioning) {
                next();
            }
        });

        $('#prev-btn').on('click', function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!isTransitioning){
                prev();
            }
        });
```

I have above html code what i want to do is that when i click on the left icon my slider should move back and when i click right icon it should go to the next slide. i have also attached the jquery code my when i click on next it is working but when i click the previous button it is not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/dnzfrudy/
i have tried in fiddle but have not attached the image and the videos

Comment: please make a fiddle

Comment: i am new to stack overflow i dont know how to use fiddle\

Comment: @P.Frank please check my jquery code my next button code is working prevous code not working

Comment: Please share content of prev()

Comment: ok, no prob and welcome on stackoverflow

Comment: @Majid Yaghouti there are background videos running

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/   use this link and provide demo

Comment: please check it i have edited my code

Comment: Can you please share your next and Prev function code.

Comment: @Mitul i have already shared all the code related to it

Comment: Where ? if you have updated in jsfiddle then share new url

Comment: also on the fiddle and the question i posted